# Enforce printing sequence but threads waiting on each other after one iteration

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am having trouble resolving this one thread waiting on another issue (even after viewing several questions posts). Here is what I am trying to do: I want one thread (called sub-thread) to print 10 times under outer-loop with 2 iterations; then another (boss-thread) to print 100 times under outer-loop with 2 iterations provided that sub-thread goes first. It will look something like this:

```
Sub Thread- iter = 1
Sub Thread- iter = 2
...
Sub Thread- iter = 10
Boss Thread- iter = 1
Boss Thread- iter = 2
...
Boss Thread- iter = 100
```

This sub-thread and boss-thread printing sequence will continue for 2 times (outer-loop). 
My implementation has unpredicatable results, i.e. it prints out first iteration of sub-thread 10 times then halts there or it rarely prints out all statements and run through both the inner-loop and outer-loop. I use `wait()` and `notify()` to enable communication bewteen threads. I am not sure if I place `synchronized` block in the wrong place or I just mis-used the `wait()` and `notify()` pairs. Here's the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main ic = new Main();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(ic.new Th1(), "Boss Thread-");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ic.new Th2(), "Sub Thread-");

        t2.start();
        t1.start();
    }

    // Boss Thread
    private class Th1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("TH1 RUNS FIRST");
            synchronized (Main.class) { // lock outside of outer loop so
                                                        // boss thread can pick up the next iteration
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
                    // wait, let the sub-thread run first 
                    try {
                        Main.class.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // print iterations 
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " iter = " + (j + 1));
                    }
                    System.out.println("end of boss outer----------------------" + (i + 1));
                    // wake up sub-thread and let it knows inner-iteration finished 
                    Main.class.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Sub Thread
    private class Th2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                synchronized (Main.class) { // lock up Th2
                    // print iterations 
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " iter = " + (j + 1)); 
                    }

                    // wake up other boss thread and let it know inner-iteration finished
                    Main.class.notify();

                    // wait for other thread to run
                    try {
                        Main.class.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("end of Sub outer---------------------- " + (i + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extra assistance needed: would someone tell me if `synchronized` is a good way of locking shared resource or other better alternatives are out there? Say `ReentrantLock`? Also, are `notify()` and `wait()` a good means to implement inter-threads communication or there are better means to make this less error-prone and more efficient?

Comment: please post your code directly in your question to avoid relying on external sources that may disappear in the future

Comment: @njzk2 As per requested, I posted the code in the description. Thanks.

Comment: There are 2 issues I can see in your code: 1st is that you have no way of guaranteeing which thread acquires the lock on `Main.class` first. 2nd is that when you call notify, you are still holding the lock (as in the doc, "The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.") although that part should be fine as there is a wait right after.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not sure about "guaranteeing" a thread owning a lock. Are you suggesting using `Lock` or there is a way to enforce that along with `synchronized`? Also, thanks for pointing "holding the lock when invoking `notify()`. But I have to use `notify()` under some kind of `synchronized` block  since it's only used if it owns a shared object (monitor), right?

Answer (score 0):

After some thoughts and efforts, I've come up with an "implementation" that "meets" my expectation as described in the question post. I have made some changes to the `wait` and `notify` pairs and added an `isTh2RunFirst` flag to assist the communication of the two threads. Here's the code:

```
public class InterThCom {
    // flag default to false for checking if sub-thread 
    // gets the lock first
    private boolean isTh2RunFirst = false; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterThCom itc = new InterThCom(); 

        Thread t1 = new Thread(itc.new Th1(), "Boss-thread-"); 
        Thread t2 = new Thread(itc.new Th2(), "Sub-thread-");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private class Th1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
                synchronized (InterThCom.class) { // lock up inner-loop

                    // boss-thread gets the lock first 
                    // wait for sub-thread and let it run;
                    // otherwise, skip this check
                    if (isTh2RunFirst == false) {
                        // wait for sub-thread, if boss-thread gets the lock first 
                        try {
                            InterThCom.class.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) { 
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } 

                    // print iteration 100 times 
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " iter-" + (j + 1));
                    }
                    // done printing 100 times

                    // sub-thread should run already at this point 
                    isTh2RunFirst = true;

                    // This print helps split boss-th and sub-th prints
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " outer-loop iter:" + (i + 1));

                    // wake up sub-thread 
                    InterThCom.class.notify();

                    // wait for sub-thread 
                    try {
                        InterThCom.class.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                } 
            }
        } 
    }

    private class Th2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
                synchronized (InterThCom.class) {
                    // print iteration 10 times 
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " iter-" + (j + 1));
                    }
                    // done printing 10 times

                    // sub-thread already prints j iteration
                    isTh2RunFirst = true; 

                    // This print helps split boss-th and sub-th prints
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " outer-loop iter:" + (i + 1));

                    // wake up boss-thread 
                    InterThCom.class.notify();

                    // wait for boss-thread 
                    try {
                        InterThCom.class.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                } 
            }
            synchronized (InterThCom.class) {
                // boss-thread is waiting at the last iteration, so wake it up
                InterThCom.class.notify();
            } 
        } 
    }

}
```

I also posted a [Code Review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207370/enforce-printing-sequence-using-wait-and-notify) if anyone feels like addressing to "proper" implementation (in terms of industry practices and efficiency) of thread-communication in detail for this specific case or others in general.